# Nginx HTTPS expectation for specific files extesions

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am using the following rule to force HTTPS:

> ```
> if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
>     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
> }
> ```

It's working pretty good. But I need to deliver some assets (for example all .XML files) in HTTP. How is possible to create an expection for these files?

I tried:

```
location ~* /sitemap*.xml {
    .
    .
break;
}
```

But it didn't work

[UPDATE]
I forget to give more details... I am using AWS and ELB, so the LB receive the HTTPS request and pass to "HTTP" internally to my EC2. So, in NGINX I just have listen on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a separate location for everything else:

```
location ~* \.xml$ {
    ...
}

location / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```